# in python how to make a dictionary of a function of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following list of lists

```
([1, 2, 3, 4], ['SHARD', 'METAL_WORK', 'FLINT', 'BONE'], ['BRONZE', 'IRON_AGE', 'MESOLITHIC', 'RECENT'], ['DOMESTIC', 'DECORATIVE', 'HUNTING', 'FOOD'])
```

I want to put this into a python dictionary such that the first list becomes the key values, and the first item on each of the following lists gets connected to the first item in the dictionary and so on. Such that `{1: [SHARD, BRONZE, DOMESTIC]}` and so on.

What's the correct script to get this?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: i'm not sure if it's a function of lists or a list of lists I have given the () brackets.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Hi Patrick!! thank you so much, that worked! Now, follow up question: how would i be able to print like a subsection of that dictionary. E.g, the first key with its corresponding values?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to zip the sublists together, then unpack the results into a key and list of values.  Something like

```
lists = ([1, 2, 3, 4], ['SHARD', 'METAL_WORK', 'FLINT', 'BONE'], ['BRONZE', 'IRON_AGE', 'MESOLITHIC', 'RECENT'], ['DOMESTIC', 'DECORATIVE', 'HUNTING', 'FOOD'])

d = {key: values for key, *values in zip(*lists)}
```

leads to

```
{1: ['SHARD', 'BRONZE', 'DOMESTIC'],
 2: ['METAL_WORK', 'IRON_AGE', 'DECORATIVE'],
 3: ['FLINT', 'MESOLITHIC', 'HUNTING'],
 4: ['BONE', 'RECENT', 'FOOD']}
```

Comment: Hi Patrick!! thank you so much, that worked! Now, follow up question: how would i be able to print like a subsection of that dictionary. E.g, the first key with its corresponding values?

Comment: @whatishappening You'd have to make a new dictionary from the existing one: `print({k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in [1, 2]})` for example

Comment: awww thanks Pat!! Bless you (-:

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip:

```
l1 = ([1, 2, 3, 4], ['SHARD', 'METAL_WORK', 'FLINT', 'BONE'], ['BRONZE', 'IRON_AGE', 'MESOLITHIC', 'RECENT'], ['DOMESTIC', 'DECORATIVE', 'HUNTING', 'FOOD'])
result = {k:list(v) for k, v in zip(l1[0], zip(*l1[1:])) }
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{1: ['SHARD', 'BRONZE', 'DOMESTIC'],
 2: ['METAL_WORK', 'IRON_AGE', 'DECORATIVE'],
 3: ['FLINT', 'MESOLITHIC', 'HUNTING'],
 4: ['BONE', 'RECENT', 'FOOD']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=  [[j[i] for j in t[1:] ] for i in range(4)]
my_dic = { k: v for k ,v in zip (range(1,5),my_list)}

output:
{1: ['SHARD', 'BRONZE', 'DOMESTIC'],
 2: ['METAL_WORK', 'IRON_AGE', 'DECORATIVE'],
 3: ['FLINT', 'MESOLITHIC', 'HUNTING'],
 4: ['BONE', 'RECENT', 'FOOD']}
```